# easy tcp socket no receive

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

Ok, I want to communicate to a python script to send data and receive an answer, but my script doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.178.25",5005);
DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
DataInputStream DIS = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
DOS.writeUTF("Dies ist ein Test");
String text = DIS.readUTF().toString();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, 0).show();socket.close();
```

Send Text are alright...but I cannot receive the data.

Comment: I downvoted your question because it lacks details: Can you tell us what doesn't work with your script exactly ? (compilation error? unexpected behavior?)

Comment: @halflings I upvoted your downvote, because the question already contains enough details to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

writeUTF() and readUTF() can't 'communicate to a Python script': only with each other. See the Javadoc.

You may need to read and write *lines.*

Comment: It may be tricky to handle this format in python, making it perhaps a poor choice, but it is not restricted to java.  And yes, end-of-line terminated sequences of characters as in your contrasting idea are quite common.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It would be extremely 'tricky'. You would have to implement not only the 16-bit length word but also the 'modified UTF-8' encoding described in the Javadoc. For all practical purposes it is Java-only.

Comment: No, the modifications are quite trivial.  Processing such data should not be difficult in any language - the only thing tricky is realizing that you need to do it by hand if a function for doing so doesn't already exist.  Realistically, any communication scheme which does not have out of band signalling available for message framing will need some sort of trickery with the codes to do so.  Line orientation merely means that a newline is either forbidden within a message, or a mechanism for escaping any mid-message newlines must be built.